# Android-universal-image-loader - loading bitmaps efficiently into memory

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

Can Android-Universal-Image-Loader load bitmaps into memory scaled down, like this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html ?

Thanks!

I'm loading images like this:

```
final ImageSize size = new ImageSize(MAX_W, MAX_H);
final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .build();
```

ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(uri.toString(), size, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
And I have two issues:

1. The resulting bitmap often has a height or width greater than the
   max I specified.
2. I worry it loaded the entire bitmap into memory and
   just scaled it down, which will fail with large images in low memory
   scenarios.

Comment: "The resulting bitmap often has a height or width greater than the max I specified" -- so will the approach in the material that you linked to. Beyond that, since the project is open source, why not [look at the source and see for yourself if you can find a reference to `inSampleSize`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=inSampleSize)?

Comment: "So will the approach in the material you linked to" true.  However one can change the scaling factor calculation to avoid this problem.

Comment: "why not look at the source yourself" I took a peek and its not clear to me how to achieve the result, so I asked.

For example, the code you linked to merely uses the inSampleSize.  It doesn't show how to find the width/height of the bitmap before loading it - to calculate what nSampleSize should be.

Comment: See https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/v1.9.4/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/utils/ImageSizeUtils.java#L63-L130 and https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/v1.9.4/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/decode/BaseImageDecoder.java#L155-L174 and https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/v1.9.4/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/decode/BaseImageDecoder.java#L101-L115.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso can, and incase it a very large image.

```
                Picasso.with(getActivity().getBaseContext())
                    .load(new File(picturePath))
                    .resize(300, 400)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.errorimage)
                    .into(imageview);
```